# How to implement an "infinite" tabbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to implement a tabbar with 3 items: (back arrow,  dateText, forward arrow)

How can I do to have sort of infinite pageView (left or right). I would like to have this behaviour :
When you press on the arrowButton, the dateText update and the view update also with the new date.

Is there any widget you recommend ? I try with a TabBar but when I pressed the forward or back arrow, it show me the new page view, but i'm block there, I can't pressed again and go further in date.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a tabbar for this case, just wrap leftArrowButton, dateText, rightArrowButton in Row,:

```
_date = currentDate

Column
  Row
    leftArrowButton: onTap (setState _date)
    Expanded
      _dateText(_date) //Widget Content consists of icons & date text
    rightArrowButton: onTap (setState _date)
  Expanded
    _widgetContent(_date) //return Widget Content based on _date
```